# Average of values of multiple selection

Tags: excel

I need to find the average Response Time for outcomes of `Busy`,  `NoAnswer`, `NoResource` or including `Refused`. (I do have other types but these are not included in the sample data.) I can get a total count of each:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(RAWDATA!K:K,{"*No*","Busy","*Refused*"}))
```

but I then need to use this filter to return the average of the Response Time. I have tried with AVERAGEIF but I get `57s` as it is not including all the values. Any help would be great.

```
Respone Time         Outcome
0                Busy
19               NoAnswer
6                NoResource
4                NoAnswer
7                NoAnswer
38               NoAnswer
58               NoAnswer
41               NoAnswer
56               NoAnswer
180              NoAnswer
72               NoAnswer
65               NoAnswer
71               NoAnswer
29               NoAnswer
105              NoAnswer
180              NoAnswer
122              NoAnswer
13               NoAnswer
23               NoAnswer
8                NoAnswer

 Average 54.85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the most elegant way to do it, but this seems to work.  You will have to adjust the ranges.

```
=SUM( SUMIF(B:B,"*No*",A:A), SUMIF(B:B,"Busy",A:A), SUMIF(B:B,"*Refused*",A:A) ) / SUM( COUNTIF(B:B,"*No*"), COUNTIF(B:B,"Busy"), COUNTIF(B:B,"*Refused*") )
```

Edit: shorter version per user pnuts

```
=SUM(SUMIF(B:B,{"*No*","Busy","*Refused*"},A:A))/SUM(COUNTIF(B:B,{"*No*","Busy","*Refused*"}))
```

Comment: Perfect that gave me exactly what I needed THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Please try dividing your formula into:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(RAWDATA!K:K,{"*No*","Busy","*Refused*"},J:J))
```